# jQuery confirmation doesn't submit

Tags: jquery, submit, form-submit, confirmation

I would like user to confirm before submit. I have a problem because when I clicked 'Yes' nothing happens or it's doing the same like 'No' button. There is part of my code:

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="add.php" name="alertowy" id="alertowy">
        <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Send</button>
    </form>
    <div id="dialog-confirm"></div>
</div>

<script>
$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function(event) {
    var submit = false;
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 190,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 330,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                submit = true;
            },
            No: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('form').submit(function() {
        if (!submit) {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Maybe I didn't include something? I added this files:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/kalendarz/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="./css/kalendarz/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="./css/kalendarz/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `&lt;form&gt;` tag has no `action` attribute, so there's no URL to which the form will be submitted. Even if you took out the javascript to let the form run as pure HTML you wouldn't be able to submit it.

Comment: I forgot to copy that. There is URL in oryginal code